# Isn't "contrast coding" just a weird way to write a mixture model?

Tags: linear-model, contrasts, data-generating-process

My background is in CS and ML, so I am quite familiar with hierarchical Bayesian models -- and probabilistic programming.  But I do not have much experience with traditional statistical methods.  This makes my understanding of the standard formalisms for linear models involving "factor variables" and "contrasts" a bit flawed, I guess.

A (1D, one variable) linear model of $Y_i$ given $X_i$, as I see it, is of the form

$$
Y_i \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\alpha + \beta X_i, \,\sigma)
$$

where the $X_i$ are continuous values, to which is applied an affine transformation, and then some noise around it.

However, when people write a linear model in R as

```
y ~ x
```

where `x` really is a categorical variable (say, with values in $\{1, \ldots, k\}$), this, if I understand correctly, designates the model

$$
Y_i \sim Normal([X_i = 1]\beta_1 + \cdots + [X_i = k]\beta_k,\, \sigma)
$$

(using Iverson brackets).  Or even something equivalent but stranger, by encoding the k values of $X$ in another orthogonal basis, in general:

$$
Y_i \sim Normal(\mathrm{encode}(X_i) \cdot \vec{\beta}, \sigma)
$$

Why isn't the formulation

$$
Y_i \sim Normal(\mu_{X_i},\, \sigma)
$$

used instead?  (Which I called a "mixture" in the title because it's really a GMM where we know the cluster assignments in advance.)

I find this much more natural to describe and interpret.  $Y_i$ does not *vary* with $X_i$ -- it discontinuously switches to a completely unrelated distribution.   The domain of the $X_i$ in contrast coding is not the same as above -- they really have to come from a simplex of some sort.  But I have never really seen this kind of interpretation -- "what is the treatment effect for a person that is given 80% of condition A and 20% of condition B"?  The value of the $X_i$ loses its inherent "topology" if we go that way.

Also, in practical terms, there is even an R package [`emmeans`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/emmeans/versions/1.5.1/topics/emmeans) that converts a linear model fit to exactly this form given through the "cluster means".

So what am I missing? Is it only computational convenience -- reducing the discrete case to the already known regression form -- or is there an interpretational advantage?  Why should I ever construct my mental model of a generative process in terms of contrasts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing mathematical notation with programming language syntax in here. [In R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976331/use-of-tilde-in-r-programming-language) `~` is a function, that creates a [`formula`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula) class object. The `formula` class is a way of defining the model structure in R in terms of target variable(s) on the left hand side of `~`, and features on the right hand side. So `y ~ x` means *"A model where we predict `y` using feature `x`"*. Formula *has nothing to do* with the statistical model underlying the relationship between variables, same formula can be used for many different models.

As about mathematical notation, the regression model is defined as

$$
y = \mathbf{X}\beta + \varepsilon
$$

what is equivalent to probabilistic notation

$$
y \sim \mathsf{Normal}(\mu_Y, \sigma)
$$

where $\mu_Y = \mathbf{X}\beta$. Here $\sim$ indeed means "is distributed as". As a slight correction to notation you used, it's $\mu_Y$, the mean of $Y$ variable, *not* $\mu_X$ ($X$ does not even have to be a random variable).